# percentages of a single column of a table in r

Tags: r

I have a table of this style:

```
     a         b   c     d
1  225.4       45  1920  1      
2  812.3       101 1930  1      
3  623.7       23  1965  2      
4  551.7       32  1975  3      
5 1374.1       91  1975  3      
6  931.0       64  1912  3
```

How can I get a proportion table of the column d that gets me something like this: `1 33.3  2 16.7  3 50.0`

With `table(df$d)` I get

```
    1    2    3 
    2    1    3
```

But with prop.table command I don't get the same results with proportions.

Comment: `prop.table(table(df$d))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both `table` and `prop.table`.

```
prop.table(table(df$d))

#        1         2         3 
#0.3333333 0.1666667 0.5000000
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `proportions` from `base R`

```
proportions(table(df$d))
```